# JavaFX setCellValueFactory

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I know, this question has been asked hundreds of times and I spent the last 3 hours reading all of them. I am writing a little Application with JavaFX (and I have done so before...). Everything is working besides putting content into my column:

```
@FXML public void initialize() {
    exerciseColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Exercise, String>("name"));
}
```

This is my initialize method and this:

```
public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}
```

is the Property Getter for "StringProperty name". The really funny thing is, that the code is the exact copy of another project I made a while ago (I double and triple checked everything of course) that I compiled again today and that is working perfectly. I read the doc for, as it feels, half JavaFX to find a solution but it just does not make any sense. If you think you need more code to help me, then I can provide it, of course.

edit: another example with the same issue (at least I hope so)

Main:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import test.model.Exercise;
import test.view.Controller;

public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private AnchorPane pane;

private ObservableList<Exercise> activeSession = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public Main() {
    activeSession.add(new Exercise("ednhzrd"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Test");

    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/view.fxml"));
        pane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Controller:

```
package test.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import test.Main;
import test.model.Exercise;

public class Controller {
@FXML private TableView<Exercise> exerciseTable;
@FXML private TableColumn<Exercise, String> exerciseColumn;

private Main main;

public Controller() {}

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    exerciseColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
}

public void setMainApp(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}
}
```

Exercise:

```
enter codepackage test.model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Exercise {

private StringProperty name;

public Exercise(String name) {
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
}

public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}
}
```

fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="209.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.view.Controller">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="exerciseTable" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="exerciseColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted. Create a [MCVE] and include it in the question. Presumably you have checked all the "is it turned on" issues (i.e. you know that the `initialize()` method is getting invoked, etc.). Did you also try converting to the more up-to-date way of doing this: `exerciseColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());`?

Comment: It definitely gets invoked, checking this with some basic outputs is always the first thing I do. I will try to reproduce the issue in a smaller version than what i have now and be back in a sec.

Comment: this was my first solution, I got it out of some tutorial but left it because I dont understand how lambdas work...

Comment: The advantage of that approach is that errors will be caught at compile time. (Typos in the string passed to the `PropertyValueFactory`, for example, will just fail silently.) So if that's compiling there is definitely nothing wrong with the code you have presented. (OT: you should really consider learning lambda expressions. They have been part of Java now for over four years, and will greatly simplify your life.)

Comment: Yeah, I had been out of Java for a long time and I would consider myself as a beginner... Is there any well written literature or any good introductions on this topic you could recommend?

Comment: The standard [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) is pretty straightforward on lambdas... Basically they are just an easy way to create an object implementing an interface with one method. (`setCellValueFactory(...)` expects a [`Callback`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/util/Callback.html)).

Comment: The issue is nothing to do with the cell value factory, it's simply that you haven't put any items in the table. Presumably you intend to call `exerciseTable.setItems(...)`, passing in the observable list defined in `Main`. (You need a little work to do this, but just wire it up. Fairly obviously, you also meant `Controller controller = loader.getController();` instead of creating a new `Controller` instance.)

Comment: Okay, this was too trivial... I was actually wondering how on earth the data should get into the table without something like that. But thanks anyway :D Seems like I should get some sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your `cellValueFactory`. The only issue here is that you never put any items in the table. If you modify the controller to add a test item to the table:

```
package test.view;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import test.Main;
import test.model.Exercise;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Exercise> exerciseTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Exercise, String> exerciseColumn;

    private ObservableList<Exercise> activeSession = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private Main main;

    public Controller() {
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        exerciseColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        activeSession.add(new Exercise("hrrykane"));
        exerciseTable.setItems(activeSession);
    }

    public void setMainApp(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
}
```

then you see the desired effect:

[image]